# Dynamic Pluralization with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I am using HTTP referer to get a string of text and match that the alt text of an image if it matches, a class from the image is removed. The problem i am having is this does not work for plurals e.g if the string is e.g cards and the alt text id card, the class is not removed, whereas it should. Below is the code im using:

Jquery:

```
$('div.bcbox img').attr('alt', function(index, value){
    return value.toLowerCase();
});

$("div.bcbox img[alt*='<?php echo str_replace('+', ' ', strtolower($whatIWant)) ?>']").removeClass("bccustom");
```

PHP:

```
session_start();
if ( !isset( $_SESSION["origURL"] ) ){
    $_SESSION["origURL"] = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]; 
}
$mysearchterm = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]; 
$whatIWant = substr($mysearchterm, strpos($mysearchterm, "=") +1);    
$whatIWant = str_replace('+', ' ', strtolower($whatIWant)); 
$querystr = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
```

Here is a [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jbas1cra/) to a fiddle with working example: when the alt text in singular, the jquery that `img[alt*='menus']` stops working for the image with the singular alt text

Comment: Can you give a full example with RENDERED HTML and let us know if you need to fix the php, the jQuery or both

Comment: @mplungjan have added a fiddle link and i need to fix the jQuery so that is works for both singular and plural words

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/w3kwocLn/)

```
var word = "menu"
$("div.bcbox img").each(function() {
  if (this.alt.toLowerCase().indexOf(word) !=-1) {    
    $(this).removeClass("bccustom");
  }
});
```

---

Old version:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/t6hw3rqf/)

```
$('div.bcbox img').attr('alt', function(index, value){
  var val = value.toLowerCase();
  return (val.charAt(val.length-1)=="s")?val.slice(0,-1): val;
});
```

Now menu will remove menus and menu

```
$("div.bcbox img[alt*='menu']").removeClass("bccustom");
```

Comment: as per your fiddle, it  does not work as the bccustom class should have been removed

Comment: in both fiddles. if i change the word to menus, it stop working. I should work for both singular and plural